# Check out project in Eclipse - SVN

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I have a project in my repository called "Dog", however when I navigate to the trunk and right click it and select check out, it puts it in my working Java directory as a project named "temp"...why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce this in Galileo on this computer, but I think you should clarify exactly what you're doing to get this result, i.e. which perspective is active.  In 'SVN Repository Exploring' I was able to to check out a project under trunk using the bare 'check out' context menu item and the project was named as I would expect.  Of course, you have more control by using the "Find/Check out as..." command, and this would almost certainly help you if you haven't tried it out.

There may also be an issue with the project files in the repo...does checking out through Eclipse work as expected on another computer?

Comment: @CodeGuy The more information on your problem that you can provide, the better, as in which version of Eclipse/plugin/SVN, what type of project, etc.

Comment: yeah, there was an issue with the project file. the XML name tag said "temp"